# Perl RegEx moving whitespace

Tags: regex, perl

I am trying to reformat some code, specifically conditional blocks, from having logic operators at the end of lines, to start of lines, as such:

```
    if ($arg == true ||
        $arg != null &&
        $arg != 42
    ) {...}
```

to

```
    if ($arg == true
        || $arg != null
        && $arg != 42
    ) {...}
```

`sed` proved insufficient, so I am trying `perl`, as such:

`perl -i'' -pe 's/ (&&|\|\|)(\s+)/$2$1 /gs' $file`

The result I get is incorrect, though:

```
    if ($arg == true
||         $arg != null
&&         $arg != 42
    ) {...}
```

It seems as though the `(\s+)` is only capturing one character, and all the remaining spaces are left where they were.  Variations I have tried have failed also.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `-p` creates a loop using `<>` which reads the file one line at a time. Hence, each time you apply the pattern, you can only match until the line break.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem I can see is the `-p` switch. It reads the content of your input file line by line and executes the regex for each one at a time. That means that the `/s` flag is useless. The `(\s+)` part matches the newline, prints it, after that prints your conditional at the beginning of next line, and so on.

Fix it reading the whole content and apply the regex to all it at once:

```
perl -i'' -0777 -pe 's/ (&&|\|\|)(\s+)/$2$1 /g' $file
```

It yields:

```
if ($arg == true
    || $arg != null
    && $arg != 42
) {...}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to get serious about reformatting Perl, download `Perl::Tidy` and use the script, [`perltidy`](http://metacpan.org/module/SHANCOCK/Perl-Tidy-20121207/bin/perltidy) that comes with it.

Answer (score 2):

You're reading the lines one at a time, but you're trying to match text spanned across two lines.

The simple solution is to load the entire file into memory by setting `$/` to `undef` using `-0777`:

```
perl -i -0777pe's/ (&&|\|\|)(\s+)/$2$1 /gs' "$file"
```

Answer (score 1):

There may be better ways of doing this, but this is what I've got:

```
perl -pe 's/(&&|\|\|)\s*$/\n/; $p=$1; $m && s/^(\s*)/$1$m  /; $m=$p;' input
```

this does not read the whole file, instead, remembers any carry over from the previous line.